# Stuck in find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, css, angularjs, selenium

I'm using this command from selenium in Python 3

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome
NamaPerekam = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="namaPerekam"]')
```

and my data contains

`<input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" id="namaPerekam" focus="selDokSumber" ng-disabled="true" ng-model="viewMonitoringController.penugasan.namaPerekam" focus-on="true" disabled="disabled">`

while hovering to the data makes a no sign on my mouse cursor

and the find_element_by_xpath function on selenium show no result

any help ?

Comment: NamaPerekam.send_keys("sample") would you try that?

Comment: @AomineDaici thanks for the help but I found out the solutions are driver.find_elements_by_id("namaPerekam")